# Best way to find parent node with a specific tag?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a modern equivalent to this function that I've had in my standard JS include for years?

```
function getParentByTag(elem, lookingFor) {
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    return parent.tagName === lookingFor ? parent : getParentByTag(parent, lookingFor)
}
```

I find it useful in a number of scenarios, e.g. to find the parent `<table>` tag of a td, or a `<form>` element that an input sits inside, etc.

Comment: Yes, there is a modern equivalent by using jQuery. With it, not only you can find the parents by tagName, but you can also find the parents with every single attributes that parent have.

Comment: jQuery is hardly a "modern" equivalent. It's an "archaic" equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rewrite it as follows, but the concept is the same:

```js
function getParentByTag(elem, lookingFor) {
  lookingFor = lookingFor.toUpperCase();
  while (elem = elem.parentNode) if (elem.tagName === lookingFor) return elem;
}
```

You could also use `document.evaluate` with an xpath such as `ancestor::table`. In very basic performance tests this was about 50% more expensive. That would look like this:

```
function getParentByTag(elem, lookingFor) {
  var result = document.evaluate(
    `ancestor::${lookingFor}`, 
    elem, 
    null, 
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, 
    null);
  return result && result.singleNodeValue;
}
```